# Need explanation for JSON parsing in Swift code

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have the following method which works fine in parsing a basic json data from an open source endpoint.  My question is, in correcting the compilation errors, I have the following line which I need help understanding:

```
let movieDictionary = json??["Search"] as! [[String:Any]]
```

Why do I need to have '??' ?  I would think I need either '?' or '!', but why '??'?  If I remove one of the '?' or replace the '??' with a '!', the Xcode insists on me adding another '?', and then my code compiles.

My full method is below:

```
func fetchMovies() {
            let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=batman")
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url! as URL) { (data, response, error) in

            if error != nil {
                print(error)
                return
            }

            do {
                let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String:Any]                                        
                let movieDictionary = json??["Search"] as! [[String:Any]]

                for movie in movieDictionary {
                    print(movie["Title"]!)
                }

            } catch let jsonError {
                print(jsonError)
            }      
       }.resume()
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The first `?`** came from `try?`. When it comes a throwable function, you have 3 options to write it:

- `try`: if the function fails, go to the `catch` block
- `try?`: if the function fails, return a `nil` and don't go to the `catch` block. Consequently, the return type is an `Optional<T>`
- `try!`: if the function fails, crash the app

**The second `?`** came from the cast: `as? [String:Any]`. You were asking the compiler to cast this over to a `[String: Any]` and return `nil` if it's not castable.

If you want to get rid of both of them:

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=batman")
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url! as URL) { (data, response, error) in
    guard error == nil else {
        print(error!)
        return
    }

    do {
        guard let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String:Any] else {
            print("Unexpected JSON format")
            return
        }
        let movieDictionary = json["Search"] as! [[String:Any]]

        for movie in movieDictionary {
            print(movie["Title"]!)
        }

    } catch let jsonError {
        print(jsonError)
    }
    }.resume()
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your solution!